# Wordpress menu editor disappears

Tags: wordpress

Since that I use a custom menu in my Wordpress template, my menu editor in the backend of Wordpress disappeared..

This is the custom menu I use: http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/responsive-flat-menu

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Considering it's a paid WP plugin, you should contact the [customer support](http://cssmenumaker.com/support) for any help about their product.

Comment: Already did, no response..

Comment: Well I don't think anyone here can help you about that - the only thing we can recommend you is to disable the plugin and get a refund.

Comment: The menu editor disappears if there are no menus defined in your theme. Did you add menus to your theme?